# Select text of a div

Tags: jquery

I have this :

```
$('DIV').on('click', function(e) {
    $('textarea').val( $(e.target).text() );
});
```

It's working well, but the thing is when I click somewhere out of the divs, it's showing me the html code of the page. I don't want that.

Have a try here :

http://jsfiddle.net/g3Cwy/

I really want just the text of a smallest div, li, ul or whatever. Let me know if I'm not clear

EDIT : I tried within a div but still the same.

EDIT 2 :

If for instance, I have this :

```
<div>
divdivdiv
<div>vidvidvid</div>
<lu>lululu</lu>
</div>
```

If I clicked on divdivdiv, I only want divdivdiv AND NOT divdivdivvidvidvidlululu

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the selector from `document` to `'div'`:

```
$('div').on('click', function(e) {
    $('textarea').val($(this).text());
});
```

You can also use `this` instead of `e.target` to get the clicked element instance.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/g3Cwy/2/)

---

> I really want just the text of a smallest div, li, ul or whatever. Let me know if I'm not clear

In this case it's much more complicated as you need to exclude children then delve in to the text nodes. Try this:

```
$('div').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var text = $(this).not($(this).children()).contents().map(function() { return $.trim(this.nodeValue); }).get();
    $('textarea').val(text.join(' '));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/g3Cwy/8/)

Comment: Well ok, but in my DIV, there is some style, script etc. So it's showing that. I just want to select the smalest Div, Lu or Li (text between > and <)

Comment: What do you mean by 'smallest'? You HTML is invalid in the example, so it's hard to tell what you mean.